# Global declaration error

Tags: python, function, loops, if-statement

Basically I'm creating a program which allows users to create a password and username. If they done it right then the program will ask them to log in. If the password and username they enter are right it will stop and say welcome.It works but it gives me a error before the program start and then it starts normally.

```
>>> 
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\password.py", line 8
    global username
SyntaxWarning: name 'username' is assigned to before global declaration
>>> 
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\password.py", line 29
    global password
SyntaxWarning: name 'password' is assigned to before global declaration
   import time

def usrname():
    total=0
    while total != 600:
        time.sleep(1)
        username=input("Create a username(must be 6 chatacters long):")
        global username

        if len(username)== 6:

            break
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Your username is invalid")
            print("Try again")
            total=total+1


def psw():
    totalP=0
    while totalP != 6:
        time.sleep(1)

        print("the password must be 5-8 characters long")
        print("Contains atlease 1 capital letter")
        password=input("please enter your password:")
        password2=input("please enter your password again")
        global password
        if len(password)>5 and len(password)<8:
            if password.title() == password:
                if password.title()==password2:

                    break
        else:
            print("Your password is invalid, please try again")
            totalP=totalP+1





option=input("Do you want to create an account(Y/N)")
if option.title()=="Y":
    usrname()
    psw()
else:
    pass

print("Hello please log in")

total3=0
while total3 < 12:
    log1=input("what is your username?")
    log2=input("what is your password?")
    if log1 != username:

        print("your  username is invaild, please try again")
        total3=total3+1

    if log2 != password:
        print("your password is invaild, please try again")
        total3=total3+1

    else:
        break
if total3 > 12:
    print("you must wait 2 days before you could enter your username again")



else:
    print("hello, wellcome to my program")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason for that. Your variables are not initialised in the scope you want to use them in. `username` and `password` variables are initialized inside the functions but then their scope ends. But your code is still working because you have the same name for the functions, so the when your write

```
if log1 == username:
```

It actually is something like this:

```
if log1 == <function username at 0x7f26d33dff28>:
```

Which is a reference to the function.

What you need to do is initialize the variables in the global scope before calling the username and password methods. Also consider naming them something else.

So do this:

```
usrname=""
pwd=""
username()
password()
```

And change code for these variables.

Refer https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html for scope information.

Comment: Thx for the help and i decided to use "global" to define password so i can use it globally.And it works finally!. But i get this error after the program finish and when i repeat it.

Comment: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\password.py", line 8
    global username
SyntaxWarning: name 'username' is assigned to before global declaration
>>>

Comment: Mind editing your question to show what you've done ?

Comment: You're assigning `username=input()` but after that you're assigning it as global, why? Instead declare `global` first and then use the `input` statement.

Comment: aha so you have to declare it global before you write the variable.Since i'm new to programming i didn't think it was a big deal

Answer (score 0):

```
    if log1 != username:
    print("your  username is invaild, please try again")
```

Its showing invalid because above reference to  "username"  is basically a call to the function name "username()" defined in your code which returns a reference hexacode value assigned to the function name variable.It will never be equal to the username you are expecting.Try the below code that prints username being compared ,you will know why its not working.

```
        if log1 != username:
            print username
            print("your  username is invaild, please try again")
```